# Make sure map finishes before return response

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I´m currently trying to create an array that searches in my database and then returns a response to frontend, but the array always returns null, is there a way to prevent the response to go before the map function is completed?

My code:

```js
      const result = await Database.raw(sqlResult)

      const data = await result.rows.map((element, index) => {
       this.getNomFun(result.rows[index].numcad)
        .then((response) => {
          const dataFun = response.toJSON()
          return {
            numcad: dataFun[0].numcad,
            nomfun: dataFun[0].nomfun,
            titred: dataFun[0].titred,
            numcpf: dataFun[0].numcpf,
            numcid: dataFun[0].numcid,
            datnas: dataFun[0].datnas,
            codccu: dataFun[0].codccu,
            nomloc: dataFun[0].nomloc,
            sms_documents_id: result.rows[index].sms_documents_id,
            register_date: result.rows[index].register_date,
            expiration_date: result.rows[index].expiration_date,
            name: result.rows[index].name,
            description: result.rows[index].description,
            time_period: result.rows[index].time_period,
          }
        }).catch((err) => console.log(`err ${err}`))
      })
      
      return data
```

Comment: `this.getNomFun()` is an asynchronous function, You need to await for it. You can try using bluebird map which allows you to `await` asynchronous function.

Comment: Use `return this.getNomFun()` to return the Promise.